# Node js app crashing a couple seconds after running on heroku with no logs

Tags: heroku, npm, webpack, babeljs

When I deploy my build, the build always succeeds and runs too. However a couple seconds after running it crashes with no logs about why. I have tested locally using the `heroku local web` command and it works flawlessly. I have also used heroku bash to check `node_modules` to ensure all my dependencies have been installed correctly. I also tried to run via heroku bash but the same error occured. Node and npm versions are the same on both local and remote with versions `node: >=10.16.0` and `npm: >= 6.9.0`. I have attempted to also copy my files (excluding `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`) into a new directory and use `npm install` and `npm run start` and still works as intended locally. Any ideas?

**Update**

I rolled back to a previous commit that was working using the heroku's rollback command and the website is up and running. I create a staging branch and pushed my changes so I am now working off of that. The thing is I just wish there was some kind of error message in the logs that would specify why its crashing because this has left me stumped for days.

**another update**

I installed ubuntu to test running my project on a linux OS to see if that would repro this issue but it still ran as normal.

** Final Update ** 
I managed to get things working by completely starting from scratch and adding one thing at a time. I know this isnt helpful but I would like to keep this question open because I still do not know what caused this issue.
**`package.json`** 

    `{
      "name": "hayewoodbotapi-v2",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "npm run prod",
        "build": "npm-run-all clean transpile",
        "server": "node ./dist-server/bin/www",
        "prod": "npm-run-all build server",
        "transpile": "webpack && babel server --source-maps --out-dir dist-server",
        "clean": "rimraf dist-server"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
        "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
        "debug": "~2.6.9",
        "ejs": "^3.0.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-generator": "^4.16.1",
        "express-session": "^1.17.0",
        "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
        "jade": "~1.11.0",
        "lance-gg": "^4.0.8",
        "morgan": "~1.9.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "passport": "^0.4.1",
        "passport-oauth": "^1.0.0",
        "passport-twitch": "^1.0.3",
        "pg": "^7.18.2",
        "query-string": "^6.12.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.5",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "sequelize": "^5.21.5",
        "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1",
        "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=10.16.0",
        "npm": ">=6.9.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
        "eslint": "^3.16.1",
        "express-swagger-generator": "^1.1.17"
      }
    }`

Here are the logs via heroku. As you can see it is executing because I added a console.log statement to output the port.

```
2020-04-30T18:50:49.307843+00:00 app[web.1]: Successfully compiled 23 files with Babel.
2020-04-30T18:50:50.111523+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-30T18:50:50.111537+00:00 app[web.1]: > hayewoodbotapi-v2@0.0.0 server /app 2020-04-30T18:50:50.111537+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./dist-server/bin/www
2020-04-30T18:50:50.111538+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-04-30T18:50:52.021984+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not    
2020-04-30T18:50:52.021997+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2020-04-30T18:50:52.021998+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process. 2020-04-30T18:50:52.028026+00:00 app[web.1]: PORT: 49175 2020-04-30T18:50:52.063057+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:138) [SEQUELIZE0004] 
DeprecationWarning: A  boolean value was passed to options.operatorsAliases. 
This is a no-op with v5 and should be removed.
2020-04-30T18:50:52.063059+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the 
warning was created) 2020-04-30T18:50:52.243126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I just needed to upgrade node version and downgrade webpack version.